# Function not working: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my function, i've sat here for a good while trying to figure out what is not working, it says its on the line where $stmt2->bind_param:

```
function addDailyTickets() {
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        id
        FROM ".$db_table_prefix."users 
        WHERE active=1
        ");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);

    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $created_timestamp = time();
        $status = "active";
        $transaction_id = "daily_".date('n-j-Y');
        $game_id = 0;
        $ticket_uniqID = uniqid("tick_");

        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."tickets (
        user_id,
        created_timestamp,
        status,
        transaction_id,
        game_id,
        ticket_uniqID
        )
        VALUES (
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?
        )");
        $stmt2->bind_param("iissis", $id, $created_timestamp, $status, $transaction_id, $game_id, $ticket_uniqID);
        $stmt2->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt2->close();    
}
```

If i put a $stmt2->error_list; right before the $stmt2->bind_param, it returns with no errors.

phpMyAdmin:
[image: phpMyAdmin]

Comment: `$mysqli->prepare` **fails**, thus you get a `bool(false)` as return, following into the error. **Always** check for errors, don't assume it just works!

Comment: Like i said at the beginning of the post, I checked for an error, and it didn't return anything.

Comment: Try `var_dump(mysqli_error($mysqli));`

Comment: De facto `$stmt2->error_list` returns another error, as `$stmt2` is not an object but a **boolean**, therefore you will never ever see a mysqli error.

Comment: I changed it to this:
http://pastebin.com/sdB19CVB

And called it: 
`$myret = addDailyTickets();`
`var_dump($myret);`

And still got nothing.

Comment: You have to do it right there. **Variables scope!!!**

Comment: Ok, so now I got the error: `string(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to @Charlotte Dunois, i figured it out, I had to put the first mysql call in an array, then close it, then call the second:

```
function addDailyTickets() {
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        id
        FROM ".$db_table_prefix."users 
        WHERE active=1
        ");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row[] = $id;
    }
    $stmt->close();

    foreach($row as $id){
        $created_timestamp = time();
        $status = "active";
        $transaction_id = "daily_".date('n-j-Y');
        $game_id = 0;
        $ticket_uniqID = uniqid("tick_");

        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."tickets (
        user_id,
        created_timestamp,
        status,
        transaction_id,
        game_id,
        ticket_uniqID
        )
        VALUES (
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?
        )");
        $stmt2->bind_param("iissis", $id, $created_timestamp, $status, $transaction_id, $game_id, $ticket_uniqID);
        $stmt2->execute();
    }
    $stmt2->close();
}
```